# Multiple stored procedures with input and output parameters called from java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to add a new row in a table - `NewOrder` which has the columns `ID, OrderDate, OrderValue` using the following stored procedure.

```
create proc [dbo].[insert_new_order](   @newID int OUTPUT,
                    @oValue float)
as
begin
insert into NewOrder values (GETDATE(),@oValue)
set @newID = @@IDENTITY
end
```

The `@newID` represents one of the input parameters for the following stored procedure which inserts a new row in the table `OrderedProduct` which has the columns `ProductID, OrderID, Price, Quantity`

```
   create proc [dbo].[insert_updates_in_ordered_product] (  @newID int,
                                                            @productID int,
                                                            @price float,   
                                                            @qty int)
    as
    begin
    insert into OrderedProduct values(@productID,@newID,@qty,@price)
    end
```

I am calling these 2 stored procedures like this:

```
     public static void addNewOrderToDB(ArrayList<Product> list){
        Connection connection = null;
        CallableStatement statement1 = null;
        String q1 = "{? = CALL insert_new_order(?)}";
        String q2 = "{CALL insert_updates_in_ordered_product(?,?,?,?)}";
        float orderValue = 0;
        //calculate orderValue

        for(Product p : list){
            orderValue = orderValue + (p.getPrice() * p.getQty());              
        }
        System.out.println(orderValue);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            statement1 = connection.prepareCall(q1);
            statement1.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            statement1.setFloat(2, orderValue); 

            ResultSet rs = statement1.executeQuery();
            int uniqueID = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(uniqueID);
            statement1 = connection.prepareCall(q2);

            for(Product p : list){
                statement1.setInt(1, p.getProductId());
                statement1.setInt(2,uniqueID);
                statement1.setInt(3, p.getQty());
                statement1.setFloat(4, p.getPrice());
            }               
            statement1.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  finally{
            if(statement1 != null){
                try {
                    statement1.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if(connection != null){
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }           

        }
 }
```

But i get this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'insert_new_order' expects parameter '@oValue', which was not supplied.
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you change like this?

```
String q1 = "{CALL insert_new_order(?, ?)}";
```

That matches your `create proc` better.